# Webchat: unable to render new elements using activitymiddleware in combication with grouping of avatars

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am not able to add new elements to webchat using activitymiddleware since the update to 4.14. As an example I added some code I use for typing indicators. As soon as I do that, the grouping of my avatar does not work anymore.

1. Without activitymiddleware and showAvatarInGroup: 'sender' -> normal behavior. Avatar is shown once per group of messages as well as the timestamp.
2. With activitymiddleware and showAvatarInGroup: 'sender' -> typing indicators are rendered as expected, timestamps are shown (but not grouped) and the Avatar is not shown at all.
3. With activitymiddleware and showAvatarInGroup : 'group' -> typing indicators are rendered as expected and the Avatar as well as the timestamps are shown. But not grouped.

Botcode (Node)
The bot sends an event to ask the webchat client to render an element. In this case a typing indicator but it could also be a new inputform.

`await context.sendActivity({ name: 'typingIndicator', type: 'event' });`

The webchat code (React) has an activitymiddleware to render this typing indicator as soon as the event is in:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';
import TypingIndicator from './TypingIndicator';

const WebChat = ({ className, onFetchToken, store, token }) => {
  const directLine = useMemo(() => createDirectLine({ token }), [token]);

  const activityMiddleware = () => next => ({ activity, nextVisibleActivity, ...otherArgs }) => {
    const { name, type } = activity;
    // first remove all existing typing indicators
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typing-indicator');
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none'
      }
    // if we reveive a typing event, render a typing Indicator
    if (type === 'event' && name === 'typingIndicator') {
      return () => <TypingIndicator activity={activity} nextVisibleActivity={nextVisibleActivity} />;
    } else {
      return next({ activity, nextVisibleActivity, ...otherArgs });
    }
  }

  const styleOptions = {
    botAvatarInitials: 'Max',
    showAvatarInGroup: 'sender', // group works ok
    botAvatarImage: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AVATAR_URL}`,
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onFetchToken();
  }, [onFetchToken]);

  return token ? (
    <ReactWebChat className={`${className || ''} web-chat`} directLine={directLine} activityMiddleware={activityMiddleware} store={store} styleOptions={styleOptions}/>
  ) : (
    <div className={`${className || ''} connect-spinner`}>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="icon">
          <span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Robot" />
        </div>
        <p>Connecting.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default WebChat;
```

The typing indicator

```js
import './TypingIndicator.css';
import React from 'react';

const {
  hooks: { useRenderActivityStatus }
} = window.WebChat;

const TypingIndicator = ({ activity, nextVisibleActivity }) => {
  const renderActivityStatus = useRenderActivityStatus({ activity, nextVisibleActivity });
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="typing-indicator">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      {renderActivityStatus()}
    </div>
  );
};
export default TypingIndicator
```

And its styling

```css
.typing-indicator {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 35px;
    width: 60px!important;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 65px;
}

 .typing-indicator span {
    line-height: 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0 1px;
    background-color: #9E9EA1;
    border-radius: 50%!important;
    opacity: 0.4;
    animation: bounce 0.7s linear infinite;
}

.typing-indicator span:nth-child(1)
{
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.typing-indicator span:nth-child(2)
{
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.typing-indicator span:nth-child(3)
{
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    30% { transform: translateY(-4px); }
    60% { transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { transform: translateY(4px); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 0.5;  }
  }
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "botframework-webchat": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the order in which I sent activities from the bot to webchat. I used to send:

1. typing-indicator event
2. message event
3. typing-indicator event
4. message event

The activity middleware would see the typing indicator event and replace the default render ('void') with a new rendering (my typing indicator).
My assumption is that the next event (the message) will be rendered without an avatar because webchat is already under the assumption that an avatar has been rendered.

To bypass this behavior my solution was to send

1. message event
2. typing-indicator event
3. message event

From a Ux perspective not such a bad idea and the problem does not occur